# How to properly send information to an API in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, rails-api

Newer to vue.js, I'm trying to figure out why it looks like my post is sent twice, once of which is nested. When I send signup information to from a vuejs app to rails api, the post request is being sent with the information wrapped twice.

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Signup',
  data () {
    return {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      password_confirmation: '',
      error: ''
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.checkedSignedIn()
  },
  updated () {
    this.checkedSignedIn()
  },
  methods: {
    signup () {
      this.$http.plain.post('/signup', { email: this.email, password: this.password, password_confirmation: this.password_confirmation })
        .then(response => this.signupSuccessful(response))
        .catch(error => this.signupFailed(error))
    },
    signupSuccessful (response) {
      if (!response.data.csrf) {
        this.signupFailed(response)
        return
      }

      localStorage.csrf = response.data.csrf
      localStorage.signedIn = true
      this.error = ''
      this.$router.replace('/dashboard')
    },
    signupFailed (error) {
      this.error = (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.error) || 'Something went wrong'
      delete localStorage.csrf
      delete localStorage.signedIn
    },
    checkedSignedIn () {
      if (localStorage.signedIn) {
        this.$router.replace('/dashboard')
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

```
app/controllers/signup_controller.rb:3:in `create'
Started POST "/signup" for ::1 at 2019-07-23 17:08:18 -0700
Processing by SignupController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"email"=>"email@ex.oc", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "signup"=>{"email"=>"email@ex.oc", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
Unpermitted parameter: :signup
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 249)
```

I see the issue is with the `"signup"=>{"email"....` part but im not sure where the issue in Vue.js is. Am I nesting the signup information anywhere?

Comment: What plugin are you using for `this.$http`?

Comment: I am using Axios to make the call so if I am understanding Vuejs correctly the plugin would be Axios.

Comment: Are you sure it's Axios? I can't find a `.plain` function in Axios, which makes me suspicious the `this.$http` has other things going on behind the scenes.

Comment: Axios is the best way, try it